# How to determine number of parametric pairs if parameters have different number of values

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have been following a book on an example to determine number of parametric pairs:

1. There are 7 parameters, each with 8 possible values.
2. To determine pairs, they use the combinatorial number (7 above 2), = 21 pairs
3. As each parameter has 8 values, a pair can have 64 values.
4. Therefore, 21*64 = 1344 possible parametric pairs

Right, but what if I have the following:

1. There are 3 parameters, 1 with 4 values, 1 with 3 values and 1 with 2 values.
2. Combinatorial number (3 above 2) determines there are 3 pairs.
3. I should then determine how many values can each pair hold but I am clueless how to do that. Anything seems too high as there is 24 possible combinations (not just pairs) and hence the number must be low.

I think the result should be 12. No idea how to get there this way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Call the three parameters A, B, and C.

Then there are three ways to choose two of them: AB, AC, and BC.

For the first pair, there are $4\cdot3=12$ values. For the second pair, there are $4\cdot2=8$ values. For the third pair, there are $3\cdot2=6$ values.

So there are $12+8+6=26$ possible values.

---

This problem can also be solved with generating functions.

Expanding $(1+4x)(1+3x)(1+2x)$, we get $1+9x+26x^2+24x^3$.

That means that there is $1$ way to pick no parameters, $9$ possible values if you pick one parameter, $26$ values if you pick two, and $24$ values if you pick three.